# How to give post parameter into sql where

Tags: php, sql

Via post (not get) method, i'mm getting id's in one file in php... How can I take this parameters into sql where method?
So example: i get: 1234, 4571, 1112; and sql must be like this: Select * from balalala WHERE id=1234 and id=4571 and id=1112... it can be one or more parameters... but how to automatize this using php and post method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your data in an array (in this example, it's called `$data`). If your POSTdata is passed as an array, just `$data = $_POST['ids']` would be fine. If you actually have a comma-separated string, then use `$data = preg_split("(\s*,\s*)",$_POST['ids']);`. Then, use this:

```
$sql = "... WHERE id IN ('".implode("','",array_map("mysql_real_escape_string",$data))."')";
```

The `IN` syntax allows you to define a list of options the ID may be.

Comment: Wait, so you're trying to find rows where the ID is 1234 AND the ID is 4571 AND the ID is also 1112? That'll never work...